# Complex Line Diagrams inside Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make following diagram in `Tikz`-
[image]

I am not able to make it completely, since positioning each node individually is very time consuming. I think that there may be some smart way to do the same job. Please see the code below-

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzset{
    box/.style = {draw, rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1.1cm, minimum height=4cm},
    cir/.style = {draw, circle, minimum width=0.5cm, text centered},
    arr/.style = {-}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (box11) [box] {};
    \node (cir11) [cir,below of=box11,yshift=+2cm] {O$_1$};
    \node (cir12) [cir,below of=cir11,yshift=-1cm] {O$_k$};

    \node (box21) [box,right of=box11,xshift=+2cm] {};
    \node (cir21) [cir,below of=box21,yshift=+2cm] {h$_1$};
    \node (cir22) [cir,below of=cir21,yshift=-1cm] {h$_n$};

    \node (box31) [box,right of=box21,xshift=+2cm] {};
    \node (cir31) [cir,below of=box31,yshift=+2cm] {h$_1$};
    \node (cir32) [cir,below of=cir31,yshift=-1cm] {h$_n$};

    \node (box41) [box,right of=box31,xshift=+2cm] {};
    \node (cir41) [cir,below of=box41,yshift=+2cm] {u$_1$};
    \node (cir42) [cir,below of=cir41,yshift=-1cm] {u$_m$};

    \draw [arr] (box11) -- (box21);
    \draw [arr] (box21) -- (box31);
    \draw [arr] (box31) -- (box41);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Below is the screenshot of generated PDF-
[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the dots it's easily manageable through `decorations`, especifically the `decorations.markings`. I've made a style that decorates the path like so. Your current way of positioning everything is functional but you could (should) make use of the `positioning` library, as it makes the code cleaner and a bit easier to understand. You can also make use of macros to define common dimensions (like the box separations and circle separations...).

I believe the difficulty you're having is the bunch of lines connecting each other, there are some examples in the Ti*k*Z manual under *Specifying Graphs* which look like that graph, so that functionality can be used. I'm assuming here that the lines are (or could be) evenly spread (in the vertical direction), although the presented drawing does not look even. To do that I made use of the `let` operation to calculate the `branch` and `grow` sizes of the `\graph`. If they are *not* supposed to be evenly spread than they have to be manually specified, but *can be* automatically connected via `\foreach` statements.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, graphs, graphs.standard, positioning, decorations.markings, calc}

\tikzset{
    box/.style = {draw, rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1.1cm, minimum height=4cm, outer sep=2mm},
    cir/.style = {draw, circle, minimum size=.75cm, align=center, outer sep=2mm, inner sep=0.2em},
    arr/.style = {-},
    shorten/.style = {shorten <=#1, shorten >=#1},
    dots/.style= {decoration={markings, mark= between positions 0 and 1 step 2mm with {\fill circle (0.75mm);}},decorate}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\circlesep{2mm}
    \def\boxsep{2cm}
    \node (box11) [box] {};
    \node (cir11) [cir,below=\circlesep] at (box11.north) {O$_1$};
    \node (cir12) [cir,above=\circlesep] at (box11.south) {O$_k$};
    \draw[dots] (cir11) -- (cir12);

    \node (box21) [box,right=\boxsep of box11] {};
    \node (cir21) [cir,below=\circlesep] at (box21.north) {h$_1$};
    \node (cir22) [cir,above=\circlesep] at (box21.south) {h$_n$};
    \draw[dots] (cir21) -- (cir22);

    \node (box31) [box,right=\boxsep of box21] {};
    \node (cir31) [cir,below=\circlesep] at (box31.north) {h$_1$};
    \node (cir32) [cir,above=\circlesep] at (box31.south) {h$_n$};
    \draw[dots] (cir31) -- (cir32);

    \node (box41) [box,right=\boxsep of box31] {};
    \node (cir41) [cir,below=\circlesep] at (box41.north)  {u$_1$};
    \node (cir42) [cir,above=\circlesep] at (box41.south) {u$_m$};
    \draw[dots] (cir41) -- (cir42);

    \draw[dots] (cir21.east -| box21.east) -- (cir31.west -| box31.west);
    \draw[dots] (box21.east) -- (box31.west);
    \draw[dots] (cir22.east -| box21.east) -- (cir32.west -| box31.west);
    \path[shift={([xshift=.4cm]cir11.east)}] let \p1=($([xshift=.4cm]cir11.east)$), \p2=($([xshift=-.4cm]cir22.west)$),
                                                 \n1={\x2-\x1}, \n2={(\y1-\y2)/3} in graph[nodes={coordinate},
                                                                                           empty nodes,
                                                                                           grow right=\n1,
                                                                                           branch down=\n2]{subgraph K_nm [n=4, m=4]};
    \path[shift={([xshift=.4cm]cir31.east)}] let \p1=($([xshift=.4cm]cir31.east)$), \p2=($([xshift=-.4cm]cir42.west)$),
                                                 \n1={\x2-\x1}, \n2={(\y1-\y2)/3} in graph[nodes={coordinate},
                                                                                           empty nodes,
                                                                                           grow right=\n1,
                                                                                           branch down=\n2]{subgraph K_nm [n=4, m=4]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

One other noticeable thing was that although you had specified `minimum width` for the `cir` nodes, most of them are exceding this minimum width (take a look at the `u_1` node, it's definetly smaller than the rest), that was making the dots different for all boxes, I tinkered with the `inner sep` of the `cir` nodes to make them comply with the `minimum width`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pics` to draw the "common components" of your diagram and then simply place these pictures where you want them. The `pics` can also take arguments, so you can pass the different labels that you need to them. The biggest advantage of doing it this way is that you only need to tweak the drawings in each component.

Doing it this way I get:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{% define a pic for the blocks, with the labels as arguments
   circnode/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=6mm, inner sep=0mm},
   pics/myblock/.style args={#1,#2}{
     code={\draw[thick,rounded corners](0,0) rectangle (1,4);
           \node at (0.5, 3.6) [circnode] {$#1_1$};
           \node at (0.5, 0.4) [circnode] {$#1_#2$};
           \foreach \y in {0.95,1.25,...,3.35} {
              \filldraw (0.5,\y) circle (1mm);
           }
      }
   },
   % and another pic for the bipartite graph
   pics/snare/.style = {
     code = { \foreach \y/\A in {0.4/A, 1.2/B, 2.8/C, 3.6/D} {
                 \coordinate (0\A) at (0,\y);
                 \coordinate (1\A) at (1,\y);
           }
           \draw(0A)--(1A)--(0B)--(1B)--(0C)--(1C)--(0D)--(1D)--(0B)
                    --(1C)--(0A)--(1D)--(0C)--(1A)--(0D)--(1D)--(0A)
                    --(1B);
     }
   }
}

\begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw (0,0) pic{myblock={o,k}};
     \draw (1.5,0) pic{snare};
     \draw (3,0) pic{myblock={h,n}};
     \foreach \x in {4.3,4.6,...,6.9} {
         \foreach \y in {0.4, 2.2, 3.6} {
              \filldraw (\x,\y) circle (1mm);
         }
     }
     \draw (7,0) pic{myblock={o,k}};
     \draw (8.5,0) pic{snare};
     \draw (10,0) pic{myblock={u,m}};
   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for using pics, nicely done. Why loading libraries though? You're not using any. `:)`

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos Thanks, I'll delete the libraries. I started with some of my own code that needed these...

Comment: absolutely beautiful !